# Finding data in a list and use it in another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, find, compare

Is there a pythonic way to do this easy and fast with lists ???? . I found some solutions with dict, but it may be slow for large data. In simplest words, find in B the values corresponding to every entry of A.

Example:

```
A = [a,a,b,c,c,c,d,e,e,f,g,g,g,...]
B = [a,1
     b,2
     c,3
     d,2
     e,1
     f,2
     g,5
     ...]
```

Expected result C (length of A)

```
C = [1,1,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,5,5,5 ... ]
```

Comment: Dicts are the cannonical way to do this, because their lookup performance is much better. How large of a data are we talking about? There might be solutions like partitioning the data and having a hierarchical lookup... but I would reach for that only if the initial solution *proves* to be slow.

Comment: yes, I agree. Actually, a did it with dic but a don't know why I had the feeling it could be faster with lists. I'm gonna compare it with the great solutions Ama suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `map` answer for completeness, though Ama's list comprehension example is equivalent.

```py
A =  ['a','a','b','c','c','c','d','e','e','f','g','g','g']
B = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f':2, 'g': 5}
C = list(map(lambda x: B[x], A))
print(C)

[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

If your data is *really huge*, you might need more complex structures, and possibly streaming, to achieve this. In the vast majority of cases you do not need this, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace ()

```
df['C'] = df['A'].replace({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f':2, 'g': 5})
```

Or you can try

```
A =  ['a','a','b','c','c','c','d','e','e','f','g','g','g']

B = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f':2, 'g': 5}

C = [B[x] if x in B else x for x in A]
```

out

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: This is essentially a dict lookup, isn't it? It's a nice solution, though! I would instinctively go for a map or list comprehension that looks up the value in a dict B.

Comment: @RecencyEffect I tried this `list(map(lambda x: B.get(x), A))` but it shows an error TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. I edited my answer, It will be useful if you could provide your answer so we can all learn. Thank you.

Comment: Weird, it works here. Will post an answer. Are you sure you were not doing `B(x)` when you were getting the error

Comment: Yes, it works. I'm not sure why I got the error earlier. I will vote for you answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Ama, you're the best. I gonna compare this approach to what I had with dic.